# Add value to array only if value isn't already in array

Tags: c++, arrays

My code so far only prevents MORE than two duplicates, but for some reason, it does allow two values to be the same.

```
if (found != string::npos && binarySearch(wrongLetters, used, guessLetter) == -1)
    {
        wrongLetters[turnNumber] = toupper(guessLetter);
        for (int i = 0; i < guessWord.length(); i++)
        {
            if (guessWord[i] == guessLetter)
                maskedWord[i] = guessLetter;
        }
    }
    else if (found != string::npos && binarySearch(wrongLetters, used, toupper(guessLetter)) != -1)
        cout << "That letter has already been used\n\n";
    else if (found == string::npos && binarySearch(wrongLetters, used, toupper(guessLetter)) != -1)
        cout << "That letter has already been used\n\n";
    else if (found == string::npos && binarySearch(wrongLetters, used, guessLetter) == -1)
    {
        wrongLetters[turnNumber] = toupper(guessLetter);
        cout << guessLetter << " is NOT in the word to guess\n\n";
        incorrectCount++;
    }
```

Comment: you might want to use a `std::set` that keeps each value only once

Comment: You seem to be just adding letters to the array and then using binary search, if I understood correctly. That won't work.

Comment: @tobi303 I've been told that's a better alternative in this case. Unfortunately, my professor has specified we must use an array :(

Comment: in that case fill them into a `set` and once you have all the uniques fill it to an array to make your prof happy

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I believe you are correct, that does appear to be the problem. What would you recommend to check if a duplicate is already contained in the array? A for loop?

Comment: Either the array has to be sorted so binary search would work or you just need to use a linear search, with a for loop for example

Comment: @tobi303 How do you copy the contents of a set into an array?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using namespace std, I suggest the following:

```
bool check = find(begin(array), end(array), x) != end(array);
```

If x is not found, find will return the location of 1 past the last place it checked.

```
if(!check)
   *add the element*
```

If it is dynamic, I suggest using vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool for the job, in this case (as @tobi303 pointed out) a `std::set` which inherently prevents multiple instances of the same item from existing inside the container.

In your case you can find out whether an insertion was successful and print a notification if it wasn't:

```
if(!letters.insert(letter).second) std::cout << "That letter has already been used\n";
```

where `letters` is the `std::set<char>` (assuming it is a `char` container in your question, it's not entirely clear) and `letter` is the `char` you are trying to insert. `std::set::insert` returns a `std::pair` whose second value is a `bool` indicating whether insertion was successful or not.